# MySQL / PDO syntax incorrect on JOINed tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I am trying to retrieve data from 2 tables using 1 select statement.

**Test one fail**

```
$sql = "SELECT banned FROM users WHERE id =:id UNION SELECT first_name, last_name, 
mobile_phone,email, city, address, postal_code, user_type, 
active FROM personal WHERE id =:id";
```

I have learned from this attempt that you can't have different number of columns selected they need to be even for that to work.

**Attempt two fail**

```
$sql = "SELECT users.banned, personal.first_name, personal.last_name, personal.mobile_phone,
personal.email, personal.city, personal.address, personal.postal_code, personal.user_type,
personal.active FROM users WHERE users.id =:id INNER JOIN personal WHERE personal.id =:id";
```

Got this: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN personal WHERE personal.id ='21'`

**Tried selecting by aliases fail**

**Last attempt fail as well**

```
$sql = "SELECT banned, first_name, last_name, mobile_phone, email, city, address, postal_code, user_type, active FROM users WHERE users.id =:id INNER JOIN personal WHERE personal.id =:id";
```

Running out of ideas what else to try or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A fresh idea: read [the documentation of the `SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). The keywords are displayed in uppercase letters and they have to stay in the order described there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax and logic are incorrect :

```
SELECT u.banned
     , p.first_name
     , p.last_name
     , p.mobile_phone
     , p.email
     , p.city
     , p.address
     , p.postal_code
     , p.user_type
     , p.active 
FROM users u JOIN  personal p ON u.id = p.id
WHERE u.id =:id
```

Some tips:

- when you are using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` you should bear in mind, that all `SELECT`s that are involved should have the same amount of fields.
- `WHERE` always goes after `FROM` and `JOIN` with `ON` clauses.

Comment: Thank that worked it was the `AS` that messed it up :( .. Will accept after timer goes thanks!